# Index type and generic function value

Tags: typescript

I have compilation error when I try the following syntax, but I don't understand why it does not work:

```
interface Param<O> {
    obj: O;
}
interface Dico {
    [key: string]: <O>(param: Param<O>) => Param<O>;
}
var x: Dico = {
    fnString: (param: Param<string>) => { return param; },
    fnNumber: (param: Param<number>) => { return param; }
};
```

Here is the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Param%3CO%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20obj%3A%20O%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Dico%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%3CO%3E(param%3A%20Param%3CO%3E)%20%3D%3E%20Param%3CO%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Avar%20x%3A%20Dico%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fnString%3A%20(param%3A%20Param%3Cstring%3E)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20return%20param%3B%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fnNumber%3A%20(param%3A%20Param%3Cnumber%3E)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20return%20param%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Compilation error is on fnString and fnNumber:

```
Type '(param: Param<string>) => Param<string>' is not assignable to type '<O>(param: Param<O>) => Param<O>'.
  Types of parameters 'param' and 'param' are incompatible.
    Type 'Param<O>' is not assignable to type 'Param<string>'.
      Type 'O' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

If I move the generic type O on interface Dico, it works but I cannot use different types like I would like:

[image]

What I am missing ? Is this a limitation I can't go around or is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you would like to achieve? 

What you've described is perfectly normal situation. In the former case `Dico` has values with generic functions accepting different `Param<T>` or the latter where all values of `Dico<T2>` accept `Param<T2>`.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the first case, a type index (no generic) with generic functions as value. The need behind is to propose an interface that others developers can implement with methods that respect a "pattern" in order to consume them in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you define as the rerun of the index is a geneic function. A generic function has its type argument decided by the caller not by the implentation, so only a generic function can be compatible with a generic function signature.

What you want is a non generic function coulpled with a way to enforce the relationship between input and output. You can do this using an extra function to help with the inference :

```
interface Param<O> {
    obj: O;
}

type Dico < T > ={
    [K in keyof T]: (param: Param<T[K]>) => Param<T[K]>;
}

function createDisco<T>(o: Dico<T>) {
    return o;
}
var x = createDisco({
    fnString: (param: Param<string>) => { return param; },
    fnNumber: (param: Param<number>) => { return param; }
    fnNumberErr: (param: Param<number>) => { return null as Param<string>; }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: As mentioned by @Titian if it's for a param that's not an object with property type, it's just Dico, createDisco and calling that createDisco function without the Param wrapping the type in all cases.